# Is there a way to find direct dependencies defined for a gradle configuration

Tags: gradle

I want to extract the dependencies defined in a particular gradle configuration; My code is like :

```
project.configurations.myConfig.files.each { src ->
        logger.debug "Extracting ${src.absolutePath} to ${to}"
        project.copy {
            eachFile { fileCopyDetails ->
                logger.debug("Extracting file : ${fileCopyDetails.file.path}")
            }
            from project.zipTree(src)

            into to
        }
```

But this is extracting the ALL the files including dependencies defined in the pom files. My requirement is to just extract the first level dependencies as defined in `dependencies{ myConfig ... }`

***Solution 1***

I tried with setting `transitive = false` and it works but that breaks the build because we are removing the dependent libraries from classpath.

***Solution 2***

Tried with creating a new configuration which is copy of `myConfig` but set `transitive = false`; And it works

I'm looking for any better solution where I do not have to copy the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a copy of a configuration, and then set the copy to non-transitive. This way you only have to specify the dependencies once:

```
// This will include dependencies from superconfigurations. If that is not
// what you want, use "copy()" instead.
def nonTransitiveMyConfig = configurations.myConfig.copyRecursive()
nonTransitiveMyConfig.transitive = false
nonTransitiveMyConfig.files.each { src ->
    // ...
}
```

See:

- [`copyRecursive()`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration:copyRecursive())
- [`copy()`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration:copy())

Comment: Yes, that works (as mentioned in my post with heading solution2). But I'm just checking if there is more efficient way where I do not have to copy the configuration.

Comment: Ah okay. I read "copy of" as: `configurations { myConfigCopy } dependencies { myConfigCopy: 'group:artifact:version' }`